# MongoDB: Find data in collection A which exist in collection B

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Collection A: List of movies with "mid" as id:

```
> db.moviesCollection.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57266290482b0b6d8ad6a8bd"),
        "mid" : 1,
        "title" : "Toy Story (1995)",
        "genres" : "Animation|Children's|Comedy"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57266290482b0b6d8ad6a8be"),
        "mid" : 3,
        "title" : "Grumpier Old Men (1995)",
        "genres" : "Comedy|Romance"
}
```

Collection B: List of the rated movies "mid"

```
> db.ratingsCollection.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57266359482b0b6d8ad6b7e8"),
        "uid" : 1,
        "mid" : 1193,
        "rating" : 5,
        "timestamp" : 978300760
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57266359482b0b6d8ad6b7e9"),
        "uid" : 1,
        "mid" : 661,
        "rating" : 3,
        "timestamp" : 978302109
}
```

My Question: How can i get all the movies titles from (moviesCollection), which exist(mid) in (ratingsCollection), The titles of the rated movies? thx in advance.

Comment: Please clarify, what do you mean with "exists(mid)" ?

Answer (score 2):

db.r -> ratings
db.m -> movies

Aggregation framework comes with $lookup from version 3.2 - which is a core part of proposed solution.

```
db.r.aggregate([{
            $lookup : {

                from : "m",
                localField : "mid",
                foreignField : "mid",
                as : "result"
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                "result" : {
                    $exists : true,
                    $ne: [] 
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Any comets welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
db.moviesCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            "mid": {
                $in: db.ratingsCollection.find().map(function(r) { return r.mid; })
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: @profesor79 I think it will, but I don't think it will perform well with large number of documents. Your solution is way better.

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from A where exists (select mid from B where B.mid = A.mid)
```

Comment: Your language is Python?

Comment: this question was posted under tags mongo,  that means answer need to meet tag requirement.

Comment: You are right, but I hadn't idea such a database nosql, apart from old Domino, could exist! hahaha